# Is it safe to ground a pump house using the water line?

Tags: wiring

I have a 2- 3/0 alum wires (overhead) from panel box to my pump house.  Both are hot there are only 2 wires no neutral nor ground wire. At the pump house they put a ground wire from the small fuse box and hooked it to the waterline heading back to main building where power originates.  How can this be safe?

Comment: Are these wires part of an aerial cable assembly (triplex), or are they run as separate (THWN or XHHW-2) wires field wound on a messenger?  Or did whoever installed this just string a pair of insulated wires between the buildings?

Comment: Perhaps it is "safety by being scary"?  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: This is a violation of the National Electrical Code.

Long answer: The Code has always required the grounding of metallic parts that may become energized. Your circuit to the pump house should contain an equipment grounding conductor. Residential systems have a voltage level that qualify under the systems that must be grounded in Article 250.20. A water pipe does not qualify as an equipment grounding conductor under Article 250.118.

If a ground fault occurs the water pipe will become energized.

Have it corrected at your earliest convenience.

Comment: That was my thought when I spotted it. Thanks for code ruling. Picking up rods and wire in the morning thanks.